# Altium designer PCB - Strange and confusing symbols everywhere (From DRC - Design Rule Checker)

Tags: pcb-design, altium, drc

I'm starting to learn Altium Designer, and I have this on my PCB screen:

[image: PCB panel]

I've tried several things, but nothing works. Here is the same image, I just moved the components away:

[image: PCB symbols without components]

Can someone explain how to get rid of these useless symbols?

They might be linked to old failed routing and re-routing changed nothing.

I checked internet, found nothing... I'm not even sure what these are called.

Comment: They come from the DRC.

Comment: @winny Ok... So, how to delete them or at least update them to fit the current components placement? I guess DRC = Design Rule Checker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run the design rule checks, "DRC error/violation markers" are added to the PCB view, showing where objects violated one or more design rules.

The simplest way to clear them is to press <kbd>T</kbd> then <kbd>M</kbd>, which is the same as accessing the **T**ools menu, then selecting Reset Error **M**arkers.

In your specific case, the lines that sort of look like a capacitor are shown for design rules under "un-routed nets:"

[image: Un-routed net design rule]

If (for some reason) you just wanted to get rid of those particular error markers, you could disable this rule and re-run design rule checks.

As others indicated, there were/are bugs in Altium which sometimes leave the error markers shown despite making changes to the PCB.

You can also simply hide them by using the System Colors section of the View Configuration panel, though I don't recommend doing this because it's possible to forget you hid them and spend precious time investigating why DRC errors aren't showing up. (This may or may not be based on experience.)

[image: System colors in view configuration panel]

Answer (score 0):

I believe they may indicate "unrouted" nets that's all... Test it by routing one of the nets and see if the symbol disapears.

Comment: I already rerouted everything (in auto mode) and it changed nothing... You can see they are linked to nothing, when I move the components, they stay in place. I added a picture in the topic

Answer (score 0):

Going to the menu "Tools" --> "Design Rule Checker" and running it updates the symbols (and therefore their position).

Just under the "design rule checker", there is the button "reset error markers" permitting to get rid of these

Comment: Yes, they are DRC left-overs.  Remaining due to poor coding in Altium.  They are not suppose to remain after you move components.  It is an Altium bug.  @zepeu's procedure should work to reset them.